# What to do after editing a module that was already on? nothing/remove cache/reindex etc (Magento 2.1)

Tags: magento2, module, cache, indexing

Say I've made a module and it's enabled. Now I change something of the module, for example edit the text in a view or add a block.

Should I do something after doing this or not? For example, flushing the cache, rebuilding indexes, removing the content of some folders etc.

Comment: Thanks, I will do it soon. One question, is removing the var folder only necessary when the module is based on admin data or category data? Thanks in advance.

Comment: After installing your module, var folder is need to remove or sometimes you have added new property inside php files constuct method. At that time you have to remove var is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have enable module.

If your system with cache management is enable then you have to clean or flush cache after changes in your view or block file otherwise its not need.

If cache enable then run command

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

If your module uses js file inside `web/js` or `web/template`and you made some changes to js or template file you have to run deploy command.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

If your module are based on admin product or category data related then you have to run indexer command.

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Remove var folder from root and refresh your changes are display.

If sometimes your changes are not display when you have made changes inside `web/js` at that time you need to clear browser cache.